# Merging using -s or -X with ours

Tags: git, github, merge

I have a project that uses Git which has a `master` branch.

#### What I wanted to do

I wanted to checkout a new branch, and do some changes.

#### What I did

I accidentally did not checkout a new branch, and did the changes on the `master` branch.

#### How I tried to solve it

When I realized that I had accidentally checked into `master`, I did the following to preserve my changes, but to move them to a new branch:

- I checked out a new branch from `master`, called `feature`.
- I reverted the last commit from `master`, using `git revert`.

#### The current situation

I then continued to work on the `feature` branch, which is now `n` commits ahead of `master`, and `1` behind (because `master` contains the reverted commit).

Now I would like to create a pull request to merge `feature` into `master`. For this to be conflict-free I first need to merge `master` into `feature`. This won't work without conflicts, because `master` contains the reverting commit, that I would love to get rid off.

Unfortunately, I can not remove the wrong commits from `master`, because `master` was already pushed, so others may depend on it.

#### How I would like to solve it

Basically, what I would now like to do is to tell Git to "merge" `master` into `feature`, but simply take the code from `feature` as the right one. In other words: I would like to tell Git to use `feature`, and skip the reverting commit from `master`, but pretend that `master` was merged into `feature` anyway.

The question now is: How to do this?

I have seen that there are two commands, of which I *assume* that they will do the right thing (although I'm not too sure here):

```
git merge -s ours
git merge -X ours
```

#### My questions

1. Am I right in that those two commands will do what I would like them to do?
2. What is the difference between them?
3. Which should I prefer?
4. Is there a better way to solve this situation?

Comment: If possible I would first try to rebase feature on master (which of cause gives you a merge conflict) and then you can merge your feature to master with no fast forward and the tree looks beautiful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git merge --strategy ours` and `git merge --strategy-option ours` are two different things.

The ours strategy merges two branches but at the same time undoes all changes that would have been introduced by the branch that is merged. (Likely this is what you are looking for.)

`git merge -X ours` applies to conflict resolution during a recursive merge. It performs the merge (where changes from both branches will be made available), but when conflicts occur (both branches changed they same line to something else) it will automatically select the branch you merged into ("ours") as the winner.

I would consider rebase to pretend your feature branch was branched off after master has been cleaned. It likely will also lead to a graph that is easier to understand.